# Gimp plugin in C++ : how to have an input from the user?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, glibc, gimp

I would like to make a watermark plugin in GIMP. I need to have the text of the watermark as input from the user. I'll try with `g_message` but it is not working: I can't read an input from user in the plugin.

Can you help?
Best regards.
Jean.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your plug in already runs and "just" needs to have the possibility to ask the user to provide a string. The easiest solution would be to add a string as input parameter - this way GIMP takes care about showing the dialog to the user before calling your script. This can be done via the `gimp_install_procedure(...)` call that I assume you are using, specifically the `params` parameter of this function: This is an array of `GimpParamDef` structs where you specify the type (`PF_STRING`), name (`"text"`) and description (`"text of watermark"`) of your input parameter.